# Does numba pass data from GPU to CPU between functions

Tags: python, numba

I'm used to breaking bigger jobs into smaller functions, provided the function does a more-or-less unique operation.  Therefore, I would typically structure my code as:

```
def func1(data):
    do something 

def func2(data):
    do something else

def func3(data):
    do something else again

# main section of code
data = importData()
data = func1(data)
data = func2(data)
data = func3(data)
```

However, if I convert these functions to run on cuda via numba (using @njit decorator) then the result is faster...but could be faster yet (i.e. I get a huge overhead hit by transferring data to/from gpu when each function is called).  However, if I convert all of my functions to run on gpu AND create a master function that also runs on the gpu will this keep my data in gpu memory, or will it still have to be piped through the cpu?  In other words, once the data are sent to the master function does the data stay on gpu memory until the master function returns the data?  Here is what I have in mind.

```
@njit
def func1(data):
    do something 

@njit    
def func2(data):
    do something else

@njit    
def func3(data):
    do something else again

@njit
def masterFunc():
    data = func1(data)
    data = func2(data)
    data = func3(data)

# main section of code
data = importData()

data = masterFunc(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general statement, code will be faster if you can avoid or minimize copying data to and from the GPU. Copying data requires the CPU and PCI bus and host memory, and all the coordination logistics there on.  The less your code does it, the faster it will be.

To your specific example, it would be even faster if you launch masterfunc() as a GPU kernel, and loop through the data within masterfunc() while calling the three functions on individual elements. This would allow numba to parallelize across the maximum number of blocks/threads.  You could compute an optimal number of blocks and threads based on data size... **be sure to include array bounds checking in the three sub functions**.

Does func2() depend on the data manipulation done in func1()? And func3() on func2()?  If not, the code might be further parallelized by allowing cuda to schedule all three asynchronously.  Not enough info here to say, but it appears like the three functions need to execute serially on a given data element?

**EDIT (after comment below):**  how data is copied to/from the GPU depends on the CUDA library version and how exactly you write masterfunc().

If masterfunc() is a CUDA kernel, everything is left to numba, and you are using pre 10.3 version of cuda...  then data gets copied CPU to GPU when masterfunc() is called, and copied back on completion.  That is the default, but numba often assumes the worst case and it may copy memory more often than is necessary (it would probably do OK with the above masterfunc example but it depends on details).

There are python ways for you (the programmer) to write the masterfunc() to assume more control of when and how data is copied. You can create data on the GPU (eg using cuPy or cuDF).  You can also assume more control using numba.cuda functions like cuda.to_device (data going to GPU) and cuda.to_host (copying data back to CPU). Assuming more control may also require the CPU code to wait for synchronize on whichever GPU stream (it’s a good idea to do so).

I have not found a Python library that gives as much control as writing native cuda C, and I guess that shouldn’t be a surprise.  For example, I created a large ndarray on the GPU of random numbers using cuPy (this calls cuRAND to generate the random numbers).   But it always allocates a new array if you call it more than once, there is no way at the moment to tell it to generate a new batch of random numbers in the existing array.  This means a lot of malloc() and free() going on behind the scenes, and more practically from a python coders perspective it means one cannot create an array bigger than half of available GPU memory (the old array doesn’t get garbage collected and free’d, before the new array gets malloc’d).  Explicitly deleting the variable (manually triggering free and garbage collection on GPU) was in my experience very slow).  One could write C code to just generate new numbers in the existing array... but that requires venturing outside of python.

Last caveat... cuda version 11 is introducing shared memory (asynchronous copying of only data that changed) and direct to GPU access of some storage media.  That was just released around May 2020, and its bleeding edge...  I saw nvidia’s announcement at GTC, but I don’t have any experience using it.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  Regarding execution of func1/2/3, this is just a dummy example, so they could be executed serially or in parallel (I had no specific intention when I wrote this).  My main questions was, when data are sent to the gpu in masterFunc do all subsequent function calls keep the data on the gpu...or does it get piped (i.e. slowed down) through the CPU as it gets passed to func1/2/3.  I think you answered that.

Comment: If I answered your question, could you please mark this as answered?